# Emojis appear on some parts of apps but show as question mark in other parts

Tags: safari, messages, font, emoji

For example, on Messages.app, the sidebar with recent contact list displays Emojis but the message pane does not:

[image]

In Safari, some Emojis [appear on sites](https://emojipedia.org/card-index-dividers/) but not [other sites](https://www.notion.so/Use-Cases-Catalog-fb4ec3f01f554c41b8ddae6fe1fa4053). Furthermore, on sites that Emojis don't work in Safari, they work in Web Inspector:

[image]

How do I fix this short of reinstalling Mac OS?

I'm on MacOS Mojave 10.14.2 (18C54). I believe it started happening since update to 10.14.1.

I've tried the Font Book > Restore Standard Fonts..., validated the fonts but not luck.

Firefox displays emojis fine.

Comment: Could you provide the url of a site where Firefox displays emojis but Safari does not?

Comment: The Emoji in the header works Firefox not Safari: https://www.notion.so/Use-Cases-Catalog-fb4ec3f01f554c41b8ddae6fe1fa4053

Comment: Plot thickens. The font of that headline that doesn't display properly in Safari is set to: `-apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Helvetica, "Apple Color Emoji", Arial, sans-serif, "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol"`. If I remove `-apple-system` it works!

Comment: I'm on macOS 10.13.6 High Sierra. I thought I had the same issue in Messages, but it was just a new Unicode 11 Emoji that High Sierra cannot display (yet?). Also, I can see card-index-dividers Emoji on both the websites you listed. It appears similar to my old issue: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/303962/15281

Comment: Further thoughts: I think this is most likely a regression of the WebKit bug listed in my old issue, so I'll make a followup comment there. The right panel in Messages is a WebKit view, whereas the left panel is not (I used the third-party app `UI Browser` to confirm this).

Comment: Do you have `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.ATS.plist` in Mojave? That's the file that `atsutil autoactivation -e` changes so "ATSAutoActivation" = "ATSAutoActivationEnable"

Comment: I bet you it was Safari Tech Preview in that case. It happened about the last time I did the OS minor upgrade which included a Safari Tech Preview upgrade. Uninstalled Safari Tech Preview and won't touch with with a ten foot poll. `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.ATS.plist` doesn't seem to exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to reinstall Mac OS. I did this by pressing Command+R on reboot and then it present a menu. You chose `Reinstall Mac OS` and it'll reinstall it for you.

I did a backup before doing this reinstall using TimeMachine and an external drive because I thought I was going to have to restore everything again.

Good news is that I didn't have to at all. All my files were intact and the emoji issue was fixed!

[Here's more info on this type of install](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904).